# Systemd fails to start openvpn in lxd managed 16.04 container

Tags: openvpn, systemd, lxd

`openvpn` starts fine from the command line using the exact `ExecStart=` call from the `systemd` unit file:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf /run/openvpn/server.pid
```

`ps ax` confirms that the process is there:

```
1634 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/
```

But `systemctl start openvpn@server` is not successful:

```
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-03-17 09:54:52 UTC; 4s ago
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 1679 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/s
 Main PID: 819 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn ovpn-server[1679]:   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn ovpn-server[1679]:   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn ovpn-server[1679]:   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn ovpn-server[1679]:   cf_max = 0
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn ovpn-server[1679]:   cf_per = 0
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn ovpn-server[1679]:   max_clients = 1024
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 17 09:54:52 vpn systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I interpret `journalctl | grep ovpn-server | tail -n 100` that it failed to fork:

```
Mar 17 09:57:44 vpn ovpn-server[1693]: OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
Mar 17 09:57:44 vpn ovpn-server[1693]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Mar 17 09:57:44 vpn ovpn-server[1693]: daemon() failed or unsupported: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
Mar 17 09:57:44 vpn ovpn-server[1693]: Exiting due to fatal error
```

Comment: This issue happened for me on OpenVZ with Ububtu 16.4 - By commenting out `LimitNPROC` as in the answer, the service started fine.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I've been looking for a fix for this also.  What I have found to work is to comment out the `LimitNPROC` line in `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service`.

Don't forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after that.

Comment: Thank you! How did you diagnose the issue? Even knowing the answer, googling for `LimitNPROC lxd` wouldn't have returned a hit that is immediately helpful to me.

Comment: I pulled a 15.10 lxd instance and started comparing the systemd config.  The LimitNPROC wasn't suspicious at first but it didn't exist in the older config so I tried removing it and it solved it.  I'd been tearing my hair out over it for a day by that point.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem too! I did have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` before it took effect.

Comment: Has this been reported?

Comment: Someone reported this as https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3336

Answer (score 20):

It's better to avoid modyfying systemd units originating from system packages. Just use systemd override drop-in:

```
systemctl edit openvpn@
```

Unit name for openvpn **server** might be different, eg. for package version `2.4.5-xenial0` it will be

```
systemctl edit openvpn-server@
```

Then put into editor:

```
[Service]
LimitNPROC=infinity
```

It should create `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service.d/override.conf` file (or similar for corresponding unit name). To activate it you may want to reload systemd with

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

If starting the unit is successful with `LimitNPROC=infinity` then go back and change the limit to a higher value than the default of `10`. The limit is important to prevent the service from consuming all available pids which can cause a denial of service.

Credits:
override: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398541/218321
"unlimited limit": https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345596/218321

Comment: this also fixes `openvpn` inside `openvz` containers

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one. I just upgraded my container and openvpn stopped to work. This was because I updated the stock systemd file instead of the override.

Comment: Note that the usage of `openvpn@` is deprecated as indicated in https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Systemd#UsingOpenVPNwithsystemdsupport

Comment: This is the method that seems to work on my lxc (proxmox) (unprivileged) (18.04.5) container as the editing of the openvpn@ did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I also had to add those bellow their respective tun brother

```
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tap rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tap1 rw
```

to run it on L2 level.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)